# How do I bind Caps Lock to Control on Windows?

Tags: keymap, microsoft-windows

What are my options for making my Caps Lock key a Control key? Can this be done within Emacs?

Comment: Can you give me an example on how or why you would want the caps lock key a control key?

Comment: @King It avoids Emacs pinky. Most key-bindings in Emacs make use of the control key, so remapping it to the more accessible Caps Lock is desirable. At least to me. Less twisting of my hand.

Comment: @King If you need to ask, you have either not been using Emacs long enough, or you haven't been using it right.  ;-)  (or perhaps you are using it in `evil-mode`)

Comment: I think I just got used to [Emacs pinky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs#.22Emacs_pinky.22). Not only that, but check out this article, [Emacs: Why You Should Not Swap {Caps Lock, Control} Keys](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/swap_CapsLock_Ctrl.html)

Comment: @nispio, I would never betray Emacs like that! I would never use `evil-mode`.

Comment: @King  I disagree with many points in the linked article.  Many keyboards are shaped in a way that pressing `Ctl` with your palm is not physically possible while maintaining your fingers on home row.  I would be willing to bet that the ergonomic keyboard recommended in the article actually falls into this category, since I have a very similar one.  I actually mapped my `RET` key to `Ctl` for a while, but I found myself making too big of a mess when I was forced to type at someone else's keyboard.  If you go too crazy with remapping keys, you can easily find yourself in a similar situation.

Comment: I think this post should be asked on super user. It's not really an emacs question.

Comment: Instructions herein courtesy of Yegge: https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/effective-emacs

Answer (score 2):

Windows has a built-in feature that lets you flexibly remap keys by adding registry keys corresponding one keycode to another.

This isn't very user-friendly to do manually, so you can get a program called [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) that's a nice GUI to this.

- Just install the program (it's small); start it up.
- Press *Add* below the empty list box.
- You can then choose *Caps Lock* from the left list and *Left Control* or *Right Control* from the right list, or do it the easy way and just click "Type Key" on the left and press your caps lock key and then okay.
- Then do the same thing on the right with either *Left Control* or *Right Control*.
- Then just hit OK, then hit *Write to Registry* in the main window.
- Once this is done you'll need to log off and then back on so that Windows will reload the keyboard settings.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, AutoHotKey should do the trick. I've red this [post](http://xahlee.info/mswin/autohotkey_swap_capslock.html), and this other [post](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MovingTheCtrlKey#toc16). Never tried this myself, so I hope it will help.

Comment: It would be useful if you could expand this, though now that I think about it, this question has multiple answers. AutoHotKey and modifying the windows registry are two that I can think of offhand. This might make it a candidate for community wiki.

Comment: @nixeagle Expand? Sorry but I can show you the trick only using xmodmap under Debian. Under Windows, I can't as I'm not a Windows user.

Comment: Right, no problem. Either someone else will answer or I will do the research and answer myself. I just think it is more useful to have the answer be fully contained. The more we link out, the more risk we take in those sites going down or being broken.

Comment: @nixeagle I'm ok with that. At least, you have a good pointer IMHO. You'll be able to dig and to answer your question.

Comment: most of the questions I posted, I already know the answers to. I am just avoiding answering unless others are unable. The only one in which I did not know the answer to is the one about listing key bindings available in a buffer as I had not had to do so for at least a year and forgot how when trying out a new major mode.

Comment: @nixeagle Answering questions you already know the answers. So the next time I'll see a question from nixeagle, I'm better stay away :)

Comment: I love emacs and I am just trying to help jumpstart this beta with common questions that I had when learning. If you feel that I should answer the questions instead of leaving it up for others I can start to do that. Ideally common stuff will already have answers for new users so that they can be helped right away.

Comment: @nixeagle I think, questions should be asked only when the answer is needed or not known IMHO, maybe I'm wrong :\ please, do as you feel

Comment: So far all the questions I have asked are things that I have had to do today. I just searched to see if the thing I wanted to do existed here, then after that I asked the question. This one can easily be answered by a simple google. But if we simply say "google it", what is the point of existing? This discussion might make a really good meta topic. Each community is different, the last one I did beta with was Mathematica which had different norms.

Comment: the more I think about it, the more I think we *should* be asking more emacs related questions. See http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68/not-yet-ready-for-public-beta The more emacs related questions we ask, the more that we demonstrate that the site is ready for public beta.

Comment: @Nsukami_ **1.** It is okay to ask questions you know the answer to. It is even ok to answer your own questions (there's a button for it when you ask). On the other hand, flooding the site with simple questions is not ok (not that I'm implying anything). **2.** This is type of meta discussion is not suited for comments. Use the chat or ask a question on meta.emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for being slightly OT, but it's been a *long* time since I used Windows.  I was kept sane back then by [XKeyEmacs](http://www.cam.hi-ho.ne.jp/oishi/indexen.html), a somewhat obscure but wonderfull program that makes Emacs keybindings work throughout Windows. Even multi-key bindings like C-x C-s work in MS Word etc.

IIRC it can also map tab to control, but perhaps that was something else.